# NSSavePanel for saving a file after sandboxing

Tags: osx-mavericks, appstore-sandbox, nssavepanel

I have a mac AVRecording app, which records a video and save it to a location selected via NSSavePanel. It was working fine till I sandboxed the app.

For sandboxing I have added the following entitlements
    com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write
    com.apple.security.assets.movies.read-write
    com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write
This enables saving to Downloads and movies folder only.

How is it possible to save my file to any desired location, Desktop, Documents etc ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether you are referring to saving a particular file (in which case you can use the `NSSavePanel` and manually copy the file using `NSFileManager` to write the file into the user-specified new file), or whether you are referring to having the user choose a location for all future downloads.

If you want to prompt the user for a location to use for future downloads, you'll need to use the secure bookmark entitlement and secure bookmarks to retain access to the folder.

There's another [stackoverflow answer about sandboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729958/remember-user-selected-folder-and-reopen-it-by-nsopenpanel-under-sandbox) which covers the process of saving and using the secure bookmark.